# cannot replicate deadlock on async await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, deadlock

I expect deadlock occurs on below code:

```
static async Task<int> DelayAndReturnAsync(int val)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(val));
    return val;
}

static async Task<int> ProcessTaskAsync()
{
    var taskA = await DelayAndReturnAsync(3);
    int num = taskA++;
    return num;
}

static void Main(string[] arg)
{
    var testTask = ProcessTaskAsync();
    testTask.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

As the main thread(current context) is put on wait after calling `ProcessTaskAsync()` and being blocked on `teskTask.Wait()`, it cannot go back to the method and continue the rest of the code when `DelayAndReturnAsync()` completed.The main thread will wait for `ProcessTaskAsync` to complete while `ProcessTaskAsync` is waiting for it(the original context) to continue with the rest of the code. Thus a deadlock.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with my understanding.
I was originally trying to replicate a deadlock and test the solution which uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` method on `ProcessTaskAsync`. e.g. `ProcessTaslAsync.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Are you trying to test this in a console application?

Answer (score 7):

That deadlock can only happen in the presence of a `SynchronizationContext` which isn't present by default in console apps. Since there's no `SynchronizationContext` to begin with it's as if every `await` implicitly adds `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

You can try it in a UI or asp.net application or even better add a `SynchronizationContext` to your test with [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext):

> "The `AsyncContext` type provides a context for executing asynchronous operations. The await keyword requires a context to return back to; for most programs, this is a UI context, and you don't have to worry about it. ASP.NET also provides a proper context and you don't have to use your own.
>
> However, Console applications and Win32 services do not have a suitable context, and `AsyncContext` or `AsyncContextThread` could be used in those situations."